# Get only one value of returned array?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, get

I am using `print_r($links[1]);` to get the following returned to the page:

```
Array
(
    [0] => lol
    [1] => this
    [2] => is
    [3] => a
    [4] => freaking
    [5] => test
)
```

How can I get the value of 0: "lol" only, and echo it back to the page?

Comment: print_r won't print just the value, it will also do the other stuff shown in his example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple:

```
echo $links[1][0];
```

Comment: @Noob Which array it returns? Please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is quite simple:

```
echo $links[0];
```